# Verifying that a Datomic entity id is valid

Tags: scala, datomic, datomisca

How can I verify that a Datomic entity id is valid?

I am using Scala and Datomisca, but any test should probably also apply to Clojure and Datomic.

I am considering using

```
connection.database.entity(id).toMap.nonEmpty
```

on the assumption that a valid entity will have at least one attribute.

Is there a better, safer way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this section](http://docs.datomic.com/entities.html#sec-4) in the Datomic docs:

> Entities are not suitable for existence tests, which should typically be performed via lookup of a unique identity.

Is probably better to use something like this (in Clojure):

```
(d/q '[:find ?a
       :in $ ?entid
       :where [?entid ?a]]
     db
     id)
```

This will return an empty set if there are no attributes related to the id. You can create a predicate function that abstracts this query:

```
(defn valid-id? [db id]
  ((comp not empty?) (d/q '[:find ?a
                            :in $ ?entid
                            :where [?entid ?a]]
                          db
                          id)))
```

I'm sorry for writing the examples in Clojure, but I don't know Datomisca.

Comment: Additional comments (consolidated from group) - you shouldn't be ending up with an entity ID in hand the status of which you're unsure of. The reasons for this are:

(1) Entities are not ideal for external facing ids - UUIDs, emails, etc. are better. See: http://docs.datomic.com/identity.html

(2) Entity IDs are not guaranteed to be preserved across databases. At present it is an implementation detail, not part of the contract, that databases preserve entity IDs on backup/restore. If you have to replay the log of one db into another, when sharding they won't be preserved.

Comment: Our application does not store entity ids in external locations, but we do return them from REST calls. The browser can then include the ids in subsequent calls, embedded in URLs. I am looking for a way to verify that an embedded id is valid and has not been erroneously changed by the browser JavaScript code ("trust, but verify").